Subplot two plotly python express choropleth maps including time animations next to each other
I would like to plot multiple plotly express choropleth maps with their own time sliders next to each other.
I have tried lots of different approaches by now, but nothing seems to work. I am aware of of this site from plotly explaining how to plot multiple express plots simultaneously, however, I don't see how I can apply their example without loosing my time animation.
I created a minimal example, including example data:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px



def plot(df):
    fig = px.choropleth(df,
                        locations='region',
                        locationmode='country names',
                        color='valence',
                        hover_name='valence',
                        animation_frame='date',
                        projection='natural earth',

                        color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Aggrnyl,
                        range_color=(0, 1))

    fig.update_traces(marker_line_width=0)
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, geo=dict(showframe=False, showcoastlines=False))
    fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0),
                      width=1500,
                      height=800
                      )


    return fig


data_2019 = {
    'region': ['Germany', 'Denmark', 'Japan'],
    'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01'],
    'valence':[0.3, 0.21, 0.1]}

data_2020 = {
    'region': ['Germany', 'Denmark', 'Japan'],
    'date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-01'],
    'valence':[0.94, 0.71, 0.81]}

df_2019 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_2019)
df_2020 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_2020)

fig_2019 = plot(df_2019)
fig_2020 = plot(df_2020)

My goal is to have the two plots appear next to each other, both with their own time slider, but with only one colorbar on the side.

I found a solution, so for anyone in the future, please check my respective post in the plotly forum.
